# Finding a place to stay between Czech border and Nuremberg

Tags: germany, hotels, czech-republic, bavaria, nuremberg

I'm driving from Prague to West Germany on the A6 and am looking for a nice place to stay overnight, preferably between Nuremberg and the Czech border. My wife and I want to interact with people, so a bed and breakfast or boarding house would be great. We're open to staying in rural or urban areas.

Do you have any tips on how to find a place to stay in Germany?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific in terms of what "good" means to you?

Comment: @Karlson Basically what I described in the question - bed and breakfasts or boarding houses. Can't say much more because I don't really know - I'm up for mostly anything as long as it's not a long drive from the highway...

Comment: May be it's just me but 300km drive isn't really conducive for a leisurely stops unless you're going somewhere specific...

Answer (score 5):

I can suggest the town of [Amberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amberg). I think it is a very pretty place to stay and somehow not touristy at all. You can reach it taking exit 66 on A6.

[image]

In the middle of the old town is a Hotel that belongs to a bar where you can meet locals. 
[Kates Amberg Hotel](http://www.kates-amberg-hotel.de/html/hotel.html).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Giving a quick look on Google I can only find 3 hotels/pension haus' near the Germany-Czech Republic border.  They are in Waidhaus which is just off the E50 route.

- [Hotel Gasthof Biehler](http://www.hotel-gasthof-biehler.de/) which from the looks of things looks like a very nice country inn.
- [Gasthof Pension Weisses Kreuz](http://www.hotel-weisses-kreuz.de/frame_hotel.htm)
- Alte Post Inh. Helene Wolf Pension  - which doesn't have a website.
- [Pension "Haus Sonnenschein"](http://www.sonnenschein-pension.de/) - which is South of E50

A local expert might add some more to the list.